# Is there a better way to access my Gmail account through nodemailer?

Tags: javascript, gmail, nodemailer

I have been accessing my gmail account through nodemailer for quiet a while now but there two issues with that:

1. If 'allow less secure apps' feature isnt used for a particular time it automatically gets disbled and emails are no longer sent and i have to enable it again everytime this happens.
2. Google says on their page that 'allow less secure apps' feature will be unavailable after May 30, 2022.

I want my website to use my gmail account to send emails to the customers. Is there a way i can get my node app registered with google or something so it is not marked as insecure.

Comment: Personally I would avoid using GMail, and use SMTP direct with MX lookups.  Yes, there is more work involved, the responsibility of re-sending is yours, if that's required.  But if you say had a Mail form, you could just send there and then anyway with any error response, no need for re-sending.  You could even install your own mail server, hMailServer is one I've used and works well, -> https://www.hmailserver.com/  You could probably just have this acting as a proxy.

Comment: @Keith Thank you so much for answering. Can you please give me a link for a tutorial or something that i can follow to use SMTP. Actually im a fresher to this and it would really help me. Thanks in advance